# Android Studio: JavaSE app

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I am working on a project which should run on Android as well as on desktop (JavaSE). For this purpose I've separated it into 3 java modules:

- AndroidApp
- CommonCore
- DesktopApp

Why I am using Android Studio (AS) is obvious. I've got almost everything to work but the "Run" button for the JavaSE module. The problem is simple: incomplete classpath. The module compiles, but it doesn't run. When I build it into JAR it runs fine. JAR includes all required dependencies. The only problem is the damn "Run" button when used on the JavaSE module.

top-level build.gradle: (pretty much generated by AS)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

CommonCore build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

targetCompatibility="1.8"
sourceCompatibility="1.8"

dependencies {
    api 'org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1'
    api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.1'
    api files('src/main/resources')
}
```

DesktopApp build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

targetCompatibility="1.8"
sourceCompatibility="1.8"

dependencies {
    implementation project(':CommonCore')
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.21.0.1'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'myproject.Main'
    }

    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

AndroidApp build.gradle: (skipped the actual android settings to keep it short)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation project(':CommonCore')
}

android { ... }
```

When I run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD
```

Apparently JVM could not find the dependency 'org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:2.3.1' from CommonCore. After examining classpath I see:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/<a ton of unused JARs>
/Users/bamboo/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/DesktopApp/build/classes/java/main
/Users/bamboo/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/CommonCore/build/classes/java/main
```

Missing entries for Gradle managed dependencies.

What have I done wrong? AS must see them because autocomplete works well.

Answer (score 0):

Place the dependency inside `runtime()` in the gradle, for example:

```
dependencies {
    runtime(
        [group: 'org.nanohttpd', name: 'nanohttpd', version: '2.3.1'],
    )
}
```

[Reference](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)

Comment: It won't compile because it is missing the lib at compile time

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is to use NetBeans with Gradle plugin for JavaSE development.